# Tensor product on a hilbert space

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

If I have the expression:

$\langle\phi|\hat{A}$ $ \otimes \hat{I}|\phi\rangle$    $      $ $ $$ $(*)

where

$\hat{A}$ is a linear operator

$\hat{I}$ is the identity operator and

$| \phi \rangle \in \mathbb{C^2}\otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ and $\langle\phi|\phi\rangle=1$

Can I simplify (*) any further? Is it equal to $0$?

Comment: I bet $\hat A$ is a symmetric or Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrix. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, apologies $\hat{A}$ is Hermitian and its matrix representation is symmetric 2x2 matirx.

Comment: Then your expression is equal to $a_{11}\langle\phi|\phi\rangle + 2a_{12}\langle\phi|\phi'\rangle + a_{22}\langle\phi'|\phi'\rangle$, where $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are the two $\mathbb C^2$-components of $\phi$, i.e., $\phi = (\phi,\phi')$ (please excuse the abuse of notation here). This is, in general, not zero. For example, if $a_{12} = 0$ and $a_{11} = a_{22} = 1$ then it is $1$.

Comment: I don't know where your expression comes from

Comment: I assume that $\hat A\otimes\hat I$ is the Kronecker product. Is that right?

Comment: It is a tensor product